# Javascript XML parser not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

I need to output a prettified XML into a HTML table. I'm using this parser in the snippet, that works fine on chrome, but doesn't works on FF.

```js
var prettifyXml = function(sourceXml) {
  var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sourceXml, 'application/xml');
  var xsltDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
    // describes how we want to modify the XML - indent everything
    '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">',
    '  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>',
    '  <xsl:template match="para[content-style][not(text())]">', // change to just text() to strip space in text nodes
    '    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>',
    '  </xsl:template>',
    '  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">',
    '    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>',
    '  </xsl:template>',
    '  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>',
    '</xsl:stylesheet>',
  ].join('\n'), 'text/xml');


  var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
  var resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
  var resultXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);
  return resultXml;
};

var prettyXml = prettifyXml('<root><node/></root>');
document.querySelector('.output-holder').value = prettyXml;
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Pretty XML output follows...</div>
  <textarea class="output-holder" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
</body>
```

Could you guys help me? Thank you.

Edit: This is the desired result (that works on chrome):

```
<root>
   <node/>
</root>
```

This is the output on Firefox:

```
<root><node/></root>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? what result are you getting?

Comment: You can run this code on FF and see where the errors are. Just open your developer tools for FF and read the console.

Comment: Or the person asking the question can add the errors to the question themselves, saving us all a bit of time.

Comment: *doesn't works* not good enough - what happens? what is expected?